# How to upload lambda function via zip file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm getting an error when I attempt to upload a .zip file that contains my lambda function: "Request-URI Too Long; The requested URL's length exceeds the capacity limit for this server."

What does this error mean? I can't find anything on it.

[image: screenshot of error message]

Answer (score 1):

Try uploading from command line

```
aws lambda update-function-code --function-name "MyFunction" --zip-file "fileb://Users//Projects/Lambda/MyFunction.zip"
```